# Stocks Financial Statements from yahoo no longer transferrinf to excel

Tags: excel, vba, finance, financial

1. I have a VBA code which transfers stocks Financial Statements (Income Statement, Balance Sheet, Cash Flows) from yahoo finance to excel, I have used it for a while now, but it seems yahoo has changed the links or something. Could someone help me re-link the links so that coding transfers the pulled information from yahoo to excel once again? Below is the coding

   Sub FinancialStatements()
       Dim ticker As String
       Dim urlend As String

   ```
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False


   ticker = Sheets("inputs").Cells(2, 1)
   If Sheets("Inputs").Shapes("Check Box 14").ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then
       urlend = "&annual"
   Else: urlend = ""

   End If



   Sheets("Income Statement").Select
   Cells.Clear

   If Sheets("Inputs").Shapes("Check Box 11").ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then

   '
       With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
           "URL;http://finance.yahoo.com/q/is?s=" & ticker & "" & urlend & "", Destination:=Range("$A$1") _
   )
   .Name = "is?s=MSFT&annual"
   .FieldNames = True
   .RowNumbers = False
   .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
   .PreserveFormatting = True
   .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
   .BackgroundQuery = True
   .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
   .SavePassword = False
   .SaveData = True
   .AdjustColumnWidth = True
   .RefreshPeriod = 0
   .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
   .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
   .WebTables = "9"
   .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
   .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
   .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
   .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
   .WebDisableRedirections = False
   .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
     End With

         End If


       Sheets("Balance Sheet").Select
   Cells.Clear

   If Sheets("Inputs").Shapes("Check Box 12").ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then

   '
       With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
           "URL;http://finance.yahoo.com/q/bs?s=" & ticker & "" & urlend & "", Destination:=Range("$A$1") _
   )
   .Name = "is?s=MSFT&annual"
   .FieldNames = True
   .RowNumbers = False
   .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
   .PreserveFormatting = True
   .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
   .BackgroundQuery = True
   .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
   .SavePassword = False
   .SaveData = True
   .AdjustColumnWidth = True
   .RefreshPeriod = 0
   .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
   .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
   .WebTables = "9"
   .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
   .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
   .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
   .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
   .WebDisableRedirections = False
   .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
       End With
          End If

   Sheets("Cash Flows").Select
   Cells.Clear
   If Sheets("Inputs").Shapes("Check Box 13").ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then

   '
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
   "URL;http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cf?s=" & ticker & "" & urlend & "", Destination:=Range("$A$1") _
   )
   .Name = "is?s=MSFT&annual"
   .FieldNames = True
   .RowNumbers = False
   .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
   .PreserveFormatting = True
   .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
   .BackgroundQuery = True
   .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
   .SavePassword = False
   .SaveData = True
   .AdjustColumnWidth = True
   .RefreshPeriod = 0
   .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
   .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
   .WebTables = "9"
   .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
   .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
   .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
   .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
   .WebDisableRedirections = False
   .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
       End With
   End If


   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

   End Sub
   ```

Comment: You might want to ask Yahoo, or check their documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I think yahoo changed it's site recently.  Just check your URL, and get that working first.

http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/IBM/financials?p=IBM

When you know that is right, engineer everything else around that.

Here is a solution that works for me.  This imports data for several tickers, listed in a sheet, in cells A2, down to the end of the array.

```
Sub Dow_HistoricalData()

    Dim xmlHttp As Object
    Dim TR_col As Object, TR As Object
    Dim TD_col As Object, TD As Object
    Dim row As Long, col As Long

    ThisSheet = ActiveSheet.Name
    Range("A2").Select
    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
    Symbol = ActiveCell.Value
    Sheets(ThisSheet).Select
    Sheets.Add

    Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    ' http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & Symbol & "/financials?ltr=1
    xmlHttp.Open "GET", "http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & Symbol & "/financials?ltr=1", False
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    xmlHttp.send

    Dim html As Object
    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = xmlHttp.ResponseText

    Dim tbl As Object
    Set tbl = html.getElementById("Lh(1.7) W(100%) M(0)")
    '

    row = 1
    col = 1

    Set TR_col = html.getelementsbytagname("TR")
    For Each TR In TR_col
        Set TD_col = TR.getelementsbytagname("TD")
        For Each TD In TD_col
            Cells(row, col) = TD.innerText
            col = col + 1
        Next
        col = 1
        row = row + 1
    Next

Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Name = Symbol
Sheets(ThisSheet).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Loop

End Sub
```

Here is a screen shot of my setup.

[image]

Comment: I understand that, but I'm not entirely sure how to corrected efficiently. I was not the one who made the coding

Comment: I guess my question would be how do I get, or what is the exact API address?

Comment: It looks like it is dynamically generated now.  It looks like the income statement, balance sheet, and cash flow statement all have table class  = Lh(1.7) W(100%) M(0)
Yahoo must have changed it recently.

Comment: Okay, I apologize for my ignorance, so that means it cannot be fixed and I should look for other sources?